# Model accuracy when training on GPU and then inferencing on CPU

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, accuracy, gpu, inference

When we are concerned about speed, [GPU is way better than CPU](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/23341/should-i-use-gpu-or-cpu-for-inference).

But if I train a model on a GPU and then deploy the same trained model (no quantization techniques used) on a CPU, will this affect the accuracy of my model? Can the accuracy of the same model degrade on a CPU?

My intuition says, GPU vs CPU should not make any difference if accuracy is concerned.

But I have one doubt that, the GPUs and CPUs have their own different ways to process the information internally. Both of them have different architecture. When a model is trained on a GPU, does the exact same way of processing happens when trained on a CPU but in much slower way? I am not concerned about the accuracy while training, but if a model was trained on a GPU, will it perform exactly with same accuracy on a CPU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results you get will be identical* for identical inputs. So for any practical purposes, the accuracy you get will not depend on whether you use a cpu or gpu.

*up to floating point precision. From [this post](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/significance-of-the-difference-between-cpu-and-gpu-results/14739/2) on the pytorch forum:

> Both are implementing the floating point number computation standard.
> So they are both correct (even though [they may be] different)

Answer (score 1):

A trained model is just a well-defined set of floats *i.e parameters*

If we go for prediction,

What it will do are a large number of *multiplication and addition* of input data and the parameters. This will be done by the ALU (*Both CPU and GPU*)

A CPU will have a few ALU and a GPU will have thousands of them. So it will complete its task very quickly.

So, unless there is a difference of precision for holding the floats which might accumulate in a Deep Network, I don't see any reason that the prediction should differ.

[image]

Comment: What if CPU and GPU are on different systems or by different vendors? still, results will be the same?